# How can I use alpha with seaborn.pointplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I guess it's changed recently since I saw several code which use alpha with pointplot ([Pointplot and Scatterplot in one figure but X axis is shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70688084/pointplot-and-scatterplot-in-one-figure-but-x-axis-is-shifting) or [Is there a way to set transparency/alpha level in a seaborn pointplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300170/is-there-a-way-to-set-transparency-alpha-level-in-a-seaborn-pointplot)) but when I use it it raise an error:

```
data = [{'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 1, 'time': 181.0, 'auc': 69.76}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 2, 'time': 193.0, 'auc': 71.12}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 3, 'time': 256.0, 'auc': 71.84}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 4, 'time': 302.0, 'auc': 71.87}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 5, 'time': 365.0, 'auc': 71.89}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 8, 'time': 602.0, 'auc': 71.87}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 10, 'time': 743.0, 'auc': 71.84}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 1, 'time': 82.0, 'auc': 69.01}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 2, 'time': 105.0, 'auc': 69.45}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 3, 'time': 171.0, 'auc': 70.11}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 4, 'time': 224.0, 'auc': 70.36}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 5, 'time': 279.0, 'auc': 70.74}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 8, 'time': 517.0, 'auc': 70.81}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 10, 'time': 654.0, 'auc': 70.98}]
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
ax = sns.pointplot(x='time', y='auc', data=data,  hue='method', 
                  alpha=.1)
```

`TypeError: pointplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alpha'`

Is there any other way?

Comment: It seems seaborn 0.11 allowed alpha with pointplot, but only applied it to the error bands, not to the points nor the connecting lines.  Seaborn 0.12 gives an error. It looks like alpha isn't supported.   (Note that your example code uses `sns.lineplot`, which does support alpha.)

Comment: According to [Is there a way to set transparency/alpha level in a seaborn pointplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300170/is-there-a-way-to-set-transparency-alpha-level-in-a-seaborn-pointplot) `plt.setp(ax.collections, alpha=.3) #for the markers` and `plt.setp(ax.lines, alpha=.3)       #for the lines` should work.  You might also want to update the legend.

Comment: @JohanC, you are right, I made a mistake. I changed it to correct one: pointplot